# What is the minimum diameter of $r$-regular, $k$-connected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $md_r^k(n)$ be the minimum diameter over all $r$-regular, $k$-connected graphs on at least $n$ vertices. (Let us assume $r, k \geq 2$).

> **Problem:** Find lower and upper asymptotic bounds on $md_r^k(n)$.

There are fewer than $r^{(d+1)}$ vertices within distance $d$ of any given vertex in an $r$-regular graph; this implies the following trivial lower bound.

> **Fact:** $\log_rn \ll_n md_r^k(n)$.

Jackson & Parson [[1982](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(82)90001-6)] showed that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist arbitrarily large $r$-regular, $r$-connected graphs with circumference at most $\varepsilon n$. When a graph is $2$-connected, the diameter is at most half the circumference, so we have the following upper bound when $r=k$.

> **Corollary:** $md_r^r(n) = o(n)$.

Can we improve either of these bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $r\ge 3$ it's not too hard to prove that a random $r$-regular graph on $n$ vertices has diameter on the order $\log n$ and is $r$-connected with positive probability. This is in Bollobas' Random Graphs book: there is a section on random regular graphs. If you want specified smaller connectivity, add a (fixed size) gadget to reduce the connectivity before generating the random regular graph. You probably have to re-do the analysis then (as the random model is a little different) but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Indeed, in Bollobas' Random Graphs (1985), for fixed $r\geq3$:
Ch. VII. Connectivity and Matchings, Theorem 32 implies that almost every $r$-regular graph is $r$-connected;
Ch. X. The Diameter, Theorem 14 implies that almost every $r$-regular graph has diameter $O_r(\log n)$.